# Nested case statement to check if person belongs to both IDs

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with records as below

```
ID NAME
-------
1  AAA
2  AAA
1  BBB
2  BBB
1  CCC
```

I want to display a column **comment** based on the **IDs** a **NAME** belongs to.

For Eg.,

```
NAME COMMENT
------------
AAA   1,2
BBB   1,2
CCC   1
```

I am using case to get the result. My query is -

```
select name, 
case when (ID = 1) then (case when (ID = 2) then '1,2' else ID end) else ID end
from table1
```

However, I am not getting desired result.

Please let me know what changes I can make in my query to get the above output.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: String aggregation techniques [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a generalization of your approach.  You need to use aggregation to do what you want.

Here is one method, by explicitly comparing the values:

```
select name,
       (case when MAX(case when id = 1 then id else '' end) = ''
             then MAX(case when id = 2 then id else '' end) 
             when MAX(case when id = 2 then id else '' end) = ''
             then MAX(case when id = 1 then id else '' end) 
             when MAX(case when id in (1, 2) then 1 end) is NULL
             then NULL
             else MAX(case when id = 1 then id else '' end) || ',' || MAX(case when id = 2 then id else '' end)
        end) as Comment
from table1
group by name;
```

This is a little tricky, because sometimes you want the comma and sometimes you don't.

The real solution is to use `listagg()` if your version of Oracle supports it.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this query maybe will be useful:

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  listagg(id,',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) 
FROM TEST
GROUP BY name
```

You can try this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24f78/7).

Note: **listagg** is available from the version 11G2.

Here this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm) for a more explanation.